# Как правильно оформить item в виджете Menu?

Tags: yii2

Мне надо получить следующее меню

```
<ul class="sidebar_nav--list">
    <li class="sidebar_nav--item"><a href="">Фрукты / Овощи <span class="count">(3)</span></a></li>
    <li class="sidebar_nav--item"><a href="">Мясо / Птица</a></li>
    <li class="sidebar_nav--item">
              <a class="active" href="">Мясная гастрономия</a>
              <ul class="sidebar_nav--sub">
                   <li class="sidebar_nav--item"><a href="">Колбасы варёные <span class="count">(1)</span></a></li>
                   <li class="sidebar_nav--item"><a href="">Колбасы варенокопченые <span class="count">(4)</span></a></li>
                   <li class="sidebar_nav--item"><a href="">Колбасы сыровяленые</a></li>
               </ul>
          </li>
</ul>
```

учитывая что `<span class="count">(1)</span>` это вычисляемое значение вот таким образом я формирую

```
foreach ($categorys as $category){
                $menuItems[$category->id]=[
                    'active' => false,
                    'label' => !$category->has_childs?"$category->name <span class='count'>".count($category->products)."</span>":$category->name,
                    'options'=>['class'=>'sidebar_nav--item'],
                    'url' => Url::toRoute(["catalog/category", 'id' => $category->id]),
                ];
        }
```

получаю но получаю вот [это](https://s.nimbus.everhelper.me/share/1319626/d3skk5fkr1hu1r0c6q1w). Подскажите  как мне правильно оформить  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

По умолчанию все что находится в `label` обрабатывается `Html::encode`, что в свою очередь является алиасом для функции `htmlspecialchars`. Чтобы убрать данное поведение вы можете добавить директиву `encodeLabels` в конфиг виджета:

```
'items' => [...],
'encodeLabels' => false,
'options' => [...]
```

Вы так же можете отменить это поведение только для одного элемента, для этого достаточно указать `'encode' => false` для этого элемента, например:

```
'items' => [
  0 => [
    'active' => false,
    'label' => !$category->has_childs?"$category->name <span class='count'>".count($category->products)."</span>":$category->name,
    'options'=>['class'=>'sidebar_nav--item'],
    'url' => Url::toRoute(["catalog/category", 'id' => $category->id]),
    'encode' => false,
  ]
]
```

Подробнее вы можете прочитать [здесь](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-menu.html#$items-detail).

Comment: затупил использовал  `'encodeLabels' =>'false'`